# Java NullPointerException during read from keyboard

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, readline

I need to read values from keyboard to table, and I guess it's going out of range, but can't figure out how to fix it.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at B12.App.main(App.java:36)

This is that line `tab.matrix[ai][aj]=parser;`

Whole code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class Matrix{
    public Matrix() {

    }
    int rozmiar;
    double matrix[][];
}

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Matrix tab = new Matrix();
        int parser;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in) );
        System.out.println("Podaj rozmiar macierzy: ");
            try {
                parser = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                tab.rozmiar = parser;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            System.out.println("Uzupelnij wiersze macierzy: ");
                for(int ai=1; ai<=tab.rozmiar; ai++){
                    for(int aj=1; aj<=tab.rozmiar; aj++){
                        BufferedReader zm = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in) );
                            try {
                                parser = Integer.parseInt(zm.readLine());
                                tab.matrix[ai][aj]=parser;
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }               
                    }
                }
                drukuj(tab);
        }

        static void drukuj(Matrix m){
            int ai,aj;
            for(ai=1; ai>=m.rozmiar; ai++)
            {
                for(aj=1; aj>=m.rozmiar; aj++)
                {
                    if(ai==1){
                    System.out.println("[" + m.matrix[ai][aj]);
                    }
                    if(ai!=1 && ai==m.rozmiar){
                        System.out.println(" " + m.matrix[ai][aj] + " " );
                    }
                    else if(ai==m.rozmiar){
                    System.out.println(m.matrix[ai][aj] + "]" );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    public double Det(Matrix m){
        double wynik = 0;

        if(m.rozmiar==1){
            wynik=m.matrix[1][1];
        }
        else if(m.rozmiar==2){
            wynik=(m.matrix[1][1]*m.matrix[2][2])-(m.matrix[1][2]*m.matrix[2][1]);
        }
        else{
            for(int n=1; n<m.rozmiar +1; n++){
                Matrix tmpM = new Matrix();
                tmpM.rozmiar=m.rozmiar - 1;
                int k=1,j;
                for(j=2; j<m.rozmiar; j++){
                    for(k=1; k<m.rozmiar; k++){
                        if(k>n) tmpM.matrix[j-1][k] = m.matrix[j][k];
                        else if(k<n) tmpM.matrix[j-1][k-1] = m.matrix[j][k];                    }
                }   
            wynik+=m.matrix[1][n]*Math.pow(-1, (j+k))*Det(tmpM);    
            }
        }

        return wynik;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is declared but never instantiated. Add this line:

```
tab.matrix = new double[parser][parser];
```

after this:

```
tab.rozmiar = parser;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `double matrix[][];` is not initilized , its `null`

Answer (score 1):

You never instantiate the `Matrix` class' `matrix` variable.  When you construct the Matrix on this line:

```
Matrix tab = new Matrix();
```

the `rozmiar` and `matrix` fields will be initialised to default (empty) values, which is `null` for the `matrix` field.

Then this is never assigned later, but you try to deference it on the line in question, which creates the NullPointerException.

The fix is to initialise the matrix when you know the size, something like this on line 23:

```
tab.rozmiar = parser;
tab.matrix = new double[parser][];
```

Note that this is a two-dimensional array, and so you'll need to create each nested array as well, e.g. on line 32:

```
for(int ai=1; ai<=tab.rozmiar; ai++){
    tab.matrix[ai] = new double[tab.rozmiar];
    for(int aj=1; aj<=tab.rozmiar; aj++){
```

A better solution though, might be to get rid of Matrix's empty constructor altogether, and instead add a constructor that takes an integer argument and sets the fields.  This is an improvement since then it's not possible to construct an object in an invalid state - it's *always* better to require arguments in the constructor, rather than to initialise an empty object later.

So this might look like:

```
class Matrix{
public Matrix(int size) {
    rozmier = size;
    matrix = new double[size][];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = new double[size];
    }
}
final int rozmiar;
final double matrix[][];
```

}

and then to use it, you wouldn't create an empty `tab` first, but would work out the size to create it, something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int parser;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in) );
    System.out.println("Podaj rozmiar macierzy: ");
        try {
            parser = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    Matrix tab = new Matrix(parser);

    // The rest as before
```